# How do I programmatically change the position of the cursor in a Mac terminal program?

Tags: xcode, macos, console, terminal, cursor-position

How do I programmatically change the position of the cursor in a Mac terminal program?  I'm teaching a couple of kids to program and we're learning by writing a little terminal game.  I've done this with C# on Windows with SetCursorPosition(x, y) so I'm hoping for something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'll be using a library like ncurses that provides an abstraction to control the terminal. However, if you want to emit the raw [ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to do this directly, you'll want the CUP code, which looks like `\e[n;mH` where n and m are the row and column numbers (1-based, origin is top-left corner) and \e is the ESC control code (0x1b).

Comment: I was afraid Curses was going to be the only option. I have a link error trying to get the move command to work, and was hoping for something different.  I'll have to post a new question.  Thanks.

Comment: I believe there's a more modern alternative to curses, but I don't remember what it's called. It's worth searching for though.